# Recommend a server-side event logging system for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, logging, analytics, flurry

We're using Flurry to track events made in our iOS app (similar to Google Analytics, Mixpanel).  It's great, but there's no way to get the raw dump of all the events that have been fired - all these analytics services will aggregate them for you.

We need the raw data to do custom queries and correlate the events with server-side information.  Ideally, it would be a hosted data logging system where we post events from the iOS side and then download logs from the server.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Localytics also supports full-data exports of session-level data for enterprise customers. (Full disclosure- I work there).

Comment: How is this accessed from within Localytics?

Answer (score 0):

We used Flurry until we had the same requirements as you. We've found the Google Analytics [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html) serves our needs well.

Comment: Oh interesting.  How are you using the Export API?  I'm trying to figure out how to make it give me an event dump and having some trouble - do you know what dimensions and metrics you are querying on?